# Instiantate ParseUser object

Tags: android, parse-platform

According to the Android API documentation in parse.com, the code below should sign up a new user. However, I get the following exception when I try to instiantate a new ParseUser: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must register this ParseObject subclass before instantiating it`. The code is the one that follows:

```
private void createUser() {
    ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
    user.setUsername(mFirstName + " " + mLastName);
    user.setPassword(mPassword);
    user.setEmail(mEmail);
    user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                // whatever
            } else {
                // whatever
            }
        }
    });
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was simply not initializing the library. Fixed!

Comment: I get this error when I initialise the library anyway. I have the exact same problem as you. Any ideas what may else cause this issue?

Comment: Do not forget to do this: ParseObject.registerSubclass. More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27635352/you-must-register-this-parseobject-subclass-before-instantiating-it

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, to solve this error, add

```
Parse.initialize(this, applicationId, clientKey);
```

to your `onCreate` method.