# You must register this ParseObject subclass before instantiating it

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am getting the following error in my `Android` application using `Parse`:

`You must register this ParseObject subclass before instantiating it.`

In my `Application` object, I am doing the following inside `onCreate`:

```
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
Parse.initialize(this, "code", "code");
```

So why am I still getting this error? It was working fine yesterday but it's all of a sudden stopped working.

This is my Manifest file:

```
 <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        ....
```

LogCat:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must register this ParseObject subclass before instantiating it.
            at com.parse.ParseObject.<init>(ParseObject.java:157)
            at com.parse.ParseObject.<init>(ParseObject.java:119)
            at usmaan.app.models.Game.<init>(Game.java:25)
            at usmaan.app.models.Game.to(Game.java:86)
            at usmaan.app.adapters.GamesAdapter.getView(GamesAdapter.java:47)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2344)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You must call
`ParseObject.registerSubclass(YourClassName.class);` 
before calling 
`Parse.initialize()`.

In addition, you need to annotate your custom class like this:

```
@ParseClassName("YourClassName")
public class YourClassName extends ParseObject
{
}
```

Finally, your custom class needs a default no-args constructor in order to be registered by `ParseObject`.

---

Reference: [Subclassing Parse Object](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#subclasses-defining)

Comment: Samuel Barbosa for President.

Comment: Is it really required? I made my projects without using it and they work perfectly.

Comment: @PsyDuck, it's required in Android when you are subclassing a ParseObject.

Answer (score 1):

You also have to put it in your Manifest like this:

```
 <application
        android:name="ParseApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"         
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

<activity
YOUR ACTIVITY 1
           />
  <activity
YOUR ACTIVITY 2
           />
</application>
```

And then try swapping these following lines

```
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
Parse.initialize(this, "key", "key");
```

like this:

```
 Parse.initialize(this, "key", "key");
 Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
```

Comment: Show the logCat as well

Comment: The Keys are perfect.

Comment: This still hasn't been fixed. Any more ideas?

Comment: You wrote "it worked fine yesterday." What did you change since then? Compare with local history. See if you find something. If no then try cleaning your code and then run.