# Parse crash on creating user

Tags: java, android, mobile, parse-platform

I am using Parse as my backend for my Android app. I have a crash report for only some android devices when I try to create a User object. The error on the crash is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
You must register this ParseObject subclass before instantiating it.
at com.parse.ParseObject.<init>(ParseObject.java:184)
```

The devices that submitted the crash report are:

```
HTC Desire 510 (htc_a11ul)  2   33.3% Android 4.4
Xperia E3 (D2203)   1   16.7%  Android 4.4
Galaxy S4 (jflte)   1   16.7%  Android 4.4
Galaxy S5 (klte)    1   16.7%  Android 4.4
```

This is extremely odd as I currently have tested my code on the Samsung Note 4, Galaxy S4, S5, and Nexus 5 without any issues. I am not sure why Parse is asking me to subclass out of nowhere as I am not trying to use the subclass functionality offered by Parse. Again, I've tested this code on other devices without any issues.

Can someone please tell me how to fix this? I have included the code below where I create the User and it crashes.

Thank you!

```
    Parse.initialize(this, "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
    user.setUsername(email);
    user.setPassword(confirmPassword);
    user.setEmail(email);
    user.put("deviceID", deviceID);
    user.put("name", fullName);

    progress = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
    progress.setMessage("Creating Account... Please Wait");
    progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progress.setIndeterminate(true);
    progress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    progress.setCancelable(false);
    progress.show();


    user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
                Intent i = new Intent(Register.this, DeviceSettingsIntro.class);
                startActivity(i);
                progress.hide();
                btnRegister.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                // Sign up didn't succeed. Look at the ParseException
                // to figure out what went wrong
                progress.hide();
                checkParseError(e);
                btnRegister.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: wild guess.  some network environments introduce an async issue where the init does not return and somehow the following expression trys to get a new parse_user OBJ.  that would cause the error msg.. Maybe Try/catch a timeout or something...

Comment: @RobertRowntree Hi Robert, thank you for the reply. I added more code showing how I actually send the User object to Parse. In terms of what you suggested, that shouldn't be the case since it should catch the error based on my code... correct? Thank you again

Comment: Do you have any class that extends ParseObject or ParseUser?

Comment: @YeahIO No, I do not. Even did a complete project search. I initiate ParseObject and ParseUser but I do not have a class that extends it. Any other ideas? Thank you!

Comment: In your source code, you do initialize Parse right before sign up. Try to initialize Parse in onCreate() method of Application and let me know. I got the same error before and that fixed my crash.

Comment: @YeahIO Thanks again. I made that change and still the same error. Any other suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: did you try to add everything from this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27635352/you-must-register-this-parseobject-subclass-before-instantiating-it

Comment: @loli thank you for the response.I dont think this is the right answer since I am not subclassing any Parse objects and the docs say subclassing is optional. I am only using the "built in" Parse User class. As well, the crash is happening on only some Android devices as mentioned above. If this was indeed needed, why is not crashing on every device? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried initializing `Parse` using an `Application` class as described by `Parse` quick start guide? Maybe `Parse` wasn't initialized successfully

**Create a class that extends Application, and for the content:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this); //might not be needed
    Parse.initialize(this, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
}
```

**Edit your manifest < application > tag, add this:**

```
    android:name="com.yourpackage.applicationclass"

//so it should look like (for example) : 
<application
    android:name="com.yourpackage.yourapplicationclass"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    //put activities here

</application>
```

This way, Parse will always be initialized when your Application launches, regardless of Activity.

Comment: Hi Reid,  thanks for the reply. Yes I have done that and I don't think that's the issue because many of the devices we have and users have work without a problem. It's just some devices. And the error isn't saying that parse wasn't initialized correctly,  it's saying I'm not subclassing parse object (mentioned in parse Android guide)  correctly which is not what I am trying to do at all. Any other suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: can you try-catch the part where you instantiate ParseUser and then check the ParseException for any error code as explained in the doc https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseException.html

Comment: what version of Parse lib and com.parse.bolts are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try register the ParseUser class before calling Parse.initialize(), like this:

```
ParseObject.registerSubclass(ParseUser.class);
Parse.initialize();
```

I know you don't need to do this, but may be a work around for your problem.
You can test and post the results!

Otherwise you can always look for more info with the parse team.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27635352/you-must-register-this-parseobject-subclass-before-instantiating-it

Comment: Hi Clayton, thank you for the response. I am confused as to why this is needed since I am not subclassing any Parse objects and the docs say subclassing is optional. I am only using the "built in" Parse User class. As well, the crash is happening on only some Android devices as mentioned above. If this was indeed needed, why is not crashing on every device? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Teddy13, you are right! subclassing is optional and you should not need to change your code. But have you tried to register the ParseUser class in your Application class ? it may worth the shot ;)

Comment: You could also make a bug report here or search for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/custom/?tag_ids=756081267746393

Comment: @Teddy13, i edited my answer, can you test this work around?

Answer (score 0):

You Added these two commands to your manifest?:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```